# Input required for datetime-local element not working

Tags: html, datetimepicker, shadow-dom

I have an app where in a modal, I am using two date-time pickers

```html
<div id="inputModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Filter By Time</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" id="inputModalClose" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <label class="display-label required" for="=startTime"> Start Time </label>
                    <input type="datetime-local" id="startTime" name="startTime" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <label class="display-label required" for="=endTime"> End Time </label>
                    <input type="datetime-local" id="endTime" name="endTime" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="modalSubmit" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

This html code is under a shadowRoot. As you notice in the code, I have set the "required" attribute at the two datetime-local elements. Still, when I click the submit button without choosing any value in the date picker, the required doesn't work. Could you help me with why this doesn't work? (Could it be because I am not using a form?)

Comment: What do you want to happen when click on the submit button?

Comment: Looks like you have an HTML `required` class not a `required` attribute. Should be `required='required'`, but you can leave that part including and after `=` off if you're not XHTML compliant.

Comment: So when I click on the submit button, I want to check if any value is chosen in the datetime picker and if it is, use the values of the both datetime pickers and retrieve some data. If any value is not chosen, I want to throw an alert to choose a value. I also tried setting required='required' for both the pickers, but it did not work

Comment: From [the MDN docs: required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) -  indicates that the user must specify a value for the input before the **owning FORM** can be submitted.